# navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition won't reset with new location on Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I'm trying to build a tracker that only requires a browser window be open, on mobile devices. All of the code seems to work, other than navigator.gelocation.getCurrentPosition. As you can see, I'm using a timer to cycle my code every few seconds. I was expecting the code within the time to output real-time location information, but instead, it seems to resort to using the last known location - or if there isn't one, it will find the location and then keep using the same one.

I'm not sure if this is an issue with Android or my code, but it seemed to work well on an iPhone - but it wasn't me who tested it, so I can't really be sure.

Thanks in advance!

```html
var lati = " ";
var longi = " ";
 
  function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
       zoom: 15
        });
        
        
        
 var timerID = setInterval(function() {   
   
 
        
 
        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map}); 
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
   lati = (position.coords.latitude);
            
   longi = (position.coords.longitude);
           
   console.log(lati, "Lol");
            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('lati');
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }
    
      function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
        infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
        infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                              'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                              'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
      }
  
   //in a loop (setInterval) get coords and apply them to database

   
  
  {
 $.ajax({ url: 'php_test.php',
     data: {'Lati': lati, 'Longi': longi},
     type: 'post',
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(output) {
                  alert(output);
              }
      
      
});
 
  }
  
 
   }, 2 * 1000); 
   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue but I realize debugging that getCurrentPosition is deprecated on insecure origins.

https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-powerful-features-on-insecure-origins

Maybe you can achieve something like [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android?rq=1)